# Iterate search over many search terms using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to do a search on LexisNexis and scrape the results. I need to scrape the results from all pages so I want selenium to do the search, scrape the data, and then click next and do it all over again. Furthermore, I want it do this search for multiple terms. So for instance, I want it to search for the term Law, do what I just described then search for the terms medicaid, do what I just described, etc..

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests
#import re
import csv
import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd

###############################################################################
#CLICKING AND SEARCH
###############################################################################

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

#Goes to library website and finds database
browser.get('https://sfx.carli.illinois.edu/sfxuiu?url_ver=Z39.88-2004&url_ctx_fmt=infofi/fmt:kev:mtx:ctx&ctx_enc=info:ofi/enc:UTF-8&ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&rfr_id=info:sid/sfxit.com:azlist&sfx.ignore_date_threshold=1&rft.object_id=63750000000001351&svc.fulltext=yes')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('LEXIS NEXIS DATABASES').click()

alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()

browser.close()
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

#Login to NexisUni through university library ONLY WHEN NOT ON CAMPUS
browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys('USERNAME')
browser.find_element_by_id('j_password').send_keys('PASS')
browser.find_element_by_name('_eventId_proceed').click()

#click on advanced search on NexisUni homepage
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH ('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[1]/header/div[3]/ul/li[1]/button'))
advancedSearch = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[1]/header/div[3]/ul/li[1]/button')
advancedSearch.click()

#Selecting Specific Content Type
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/h2/ul/li/div/button')))
Select_Content = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/h2/ul/li/div/button')
Select_Content.click()

#Choose News
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/h2/ul/li/div/aside/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/button')))
Choose_News = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/header/h2/ul/li/div/aside/div[2]/ul[2]/li[2]/button')
Choose_News.click()

#Type in Search Term
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="headline"]').send_keys('Law')

#Type in Publication
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//*[@id="publication"]')))
Pub = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="publication"]')
Pub.send_keys('The Associated Press')

#input date range
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('date'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Date is after')
browser.find_element_by_id('dateFrom').send_keys('01/01/1980')

#click on Search
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/footer/span/button[1]')))
Search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[13]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/footer/span/button[1]')
Search.click()      

###############################################################################
#SCRAPING
###############################################################################
scd = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(scd, "lxml")

HEADLINES = soup.findAll('a', attrs={"data-action":"title"})
headlines=[]
for H in HEADLINES:
    headlines.append(H.text.strip())

DETAILS = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"dataInfo translate"})
details = []
for D in DETAILS:
    details.append(D.text.strip())


Dates1 = [i.split('\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',2)[1] for i in details]
Dates = [i.split('\n',1)[0] for i in Dates1]

Source1 = [i.split('\t\t\t\t\t\n\n',1)[1] for i in details]
Source = [i.split('\n',1)[1] for i in Source1]


News = zip(headlines,Dates,Source)

result = "/Users/danashaat/Desktop/data.csv"
with open(result, 'a') as result:
    newswriter = csv.writer(result) 
    for row in News:
        newswriter.writerow(row)

#Next Page:
while True:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH('/html/body/main/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/nav/ol/li[7]/a')))
    Next = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/nav/ol/li[7]/a')
    if len(Next) < 1:
        print("No more pages left")
        break
    else:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH('/html/body/main/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/nav/ol/li[7]/a')))
        Next = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/nav/ol/li[7]/a')
        Next.click()
```

It is not working the way I want it to! and I am not sure why :/

Comment: _It is not working the way I want it to_ It's hard for us to help with such a vague problem description.  What is it doing, and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: Apologies. What I meant was that it is not clicking on next, scraping, and clicking next again. It just clicks next once. It keeps running and prints "No More Pages Left" without going to new pages. I would have put a link but you have to be logged on to lexisNexis so the link would just take you to the home page and not the search results.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop at the end of code will just keep on clicking on 'Next' button until 'No more pages left' message is displayed. It is not calling the 'Scraping' part of your code again after clicking on 'Next'. So your code will just scrape the first page and save zip file, but then will just keep on clicking 'Next' until it exists.

May be you should create a function for scraping and call it in the while loop after clicking on 'Next' button each time.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I will try that!